# JqPlot : Set a fix height value for the graph area not including y axe labels

Tags: jquery, graphics, jqplot

I am using JqPlot.

The graph height is depending on the height of the main container or the default JqPlot value.

My problem is that if the y label is very long, the graph size is reduced to fit in the main container.

Is it possible to set a fix value for the graph height which is not depending on the label text length?

My need : I would like always display the same graph height (400px for example) not depending on the y label text length

Here is an image to depict my problem:

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is it you're wanting to do: expand the graph height or shorten the label. It would seem those are the only two choices if I understnad what you're saying.

Comment: I would like always display the same graph height (400px for example) not depending on the y label text length

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Only thing that comes to my mind is something along these lines [presented in this sample.](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/AqKZz/33/)
After the call to paint the plot, call the below code to get the current plot's size and adjust it accordingly by adding the size taken by the surrounding divs (i.e. title & axes).
In result whatever you set for the size of your chart in `CSS` will be taken by the graphical part of the chart, just as you want it.

```
var w = parseInt($(".jqplot-yaxis").width(), 10) + parseInt($("#chart").width(), 10);
var h = parseInt($(".jqplot-title").height(), 10) + parseInt($(".jqplot-xaxis").height(), 10) + parseInt($("#chart").height(), 10);
$("#chart").width(w).height(h);
plot.replot();
```

Comment: If you don't save the 'plot' variable you can also do: $("#chart").data("jqplot").replot();