# jqPlot Resize Chart after AJAX call

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I am using a jqPlot to display a horizontal bar chart with the data in the yAxis being a dynamic number of points.  The data is being loaded using the AjaxDataRenderer.  Since the number of points on yAxis is dynamic, I need to change the height of jqPlot container div so the bars are the same size no matter what.  I need to change the height based on the data that comes back from the ajax call.

I have tested this by adding a click handler on a button to resize the chart contaniner div.  This works fine.  My question is how can I change the height after the ajax call returns but before the chart the rendered?

Answer (score 0):

I had this kind of problem few weeks ago.

Check [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229577/jqplot-set-a-fix-height-value-for-the-graph-area-not-including-y-axe-labels), Boro exlpains how you can set a fix height and width of your graph.