# x-axis exceeds div width

Tags: javascript, html, css, jqplot

I'm drawing bar charts using `jqplot`. If the maximum value of x-axis is not too big everything seems to be fine, like this:
[image]

but if it's large I'm getting this:
[image]

x-axis seems to be wider than the div I'm using to draw chart in.

This div has the following style:

```
.barChart {
    min-width: 735px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    height: 200px;
    color: #333;
    background: white;
    overflow: auto;
    border-top: 2px solid #369;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #369;
    line-height: 14px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

So, how can I make x-axis be not wider than the div with a chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply a specific chart size. I opened a question on this topic here : [JqPlot : Set a fix height value for the graph area not including y axe labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229577/jqplot-set-a-fix-height-value-for-the-graph-area-not-including-y-axe-labels)

The solution was to replot with exact chart size like this :

```
var w = parseInt($(".jqplot-yaxis").width(), 10) + parseInt($("#chart").width(), 10);
var h = parseInt($(".jqplot-title").height(), 10) + parseInt($(".jqplot-xaxis").height(), 10) + parseInt($("#chart").height(), 10);
$("#chart").width(w).height(h);
plot.replot();
```

Hope it is help

Comment: thanks for the feedback, your solution gave me an idea on how to solve this. I've just made a div a bit wider without replotting by `$("#" + el).width($("#" + el).width() + 5);`