# jqplot - yaxis display only 2 characters

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I have a plot that it's yaxis needs to have the possibility to render from 0 to 150M
however i have a small place to put it in my site (130X70) and my problem is that the yaxis number (most likely to be im millions) are taking all of my space and the plot it is 1/3 of the size I want it to be... how can I "render" it so I'll only see 2 Chars? (for Ex 20,000,000 will become 20.)

Thanks, and sorry for my bad English...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked a related question few month ago.

Have a look : [JqPlot : Set a fix height value for the graph area not including y axe labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229577/jqplot-set-a-fix-height-value-for-the-graph-area-not-including-y-axe-labels)

The idea was to reset the chart height and width after creation, then replot

```
var w = parseInt($(".jqplot-yaxis").width(), 10) + parseInt($("#chart").width(), 10);
var h = parseInt($(".jqplot-title").height(), 10) + parseInt($(".jqplot-xaxis").height(), 10) + parseInt($("#chart").height(), 10);
$("#chart").width(w).height(h);
plot.replot();
```