# jqplot: width, height, label position, min&max value

Tags: jqplot

I am a newbie to jqPlot and I am currently using it to generate charts
so I need you helps for some questions following please

1. I would like to do a chart like this http://picturepush.com/public/11972209 
   but I don't want show the min and max values de axis X (min = 99, max = 106).
   (NOTHING ELSE CHANGES!)
2. how could I fix the **W**idth and **H**eigh of the 'rectangle' of chart?
   (independently with the label ticks, axis label, legend ...)
3. how could I set the position of xaxis, yaxis label?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

About your questions :

1. You can set the ticks you want using `ticks` options : http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Axis.ticks
2. Here is a related question I asked some months ago : [JqPlot : Set a fix height value for the graph area not including y axe labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229577/jqplot-set-a-fix-height-value-for-the-graph-area-not-including-y-axe-labels)
3. You should have a look here : http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-axisTickRenderer-js.html#

Comment: 1. i ready used ticks but ticks[0] is always aligned with y-axis. Idem ticks[ticks.length-1]
2. i did see your question but it seems KO for me. But i will try again
3. not position option
thanks