# JqPlot graph too wide

Tags: javascript, html, width, jqplot

I am using JqPlot and have a question about the width of the graph. Here is an image of the graph when displayed:

[image: Div Image]

The graph is just a little bit too wide. Can I please have some help to get it to be a little bit smaller in width. Here is the DIV code:

```
<div id="box6">
<div class="extrawidechartbox">
    <div id="totalTakings" style="margin: 20px 0; width:1000px; height:500px;"></div>
    <table style='width: 1000px; margin: 0 20px'> 
                <thead> 
                <tr> 
                    <th>Select</th> 
                    <th>Day</th>                
                </tr> 
                </thead> 
                <tbody> 

    <? //print_r($takingsArray); ?>         
    <tr>
        <td width='30'><input type='checkbox' name='day_name0' class='daycheck' value='0' <? echo ($takingsArray[0]=='no data')?' disabled ':''; ?>></td>
        <td align='left' width='80' class='day'><a href='#' style='color:#329dd5;font-weight:bold'>Week Totals</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width='30'><input type='checkbox' name='day_name1' class='daycheck' value='1' checked <? echo ($takingsArray[1]=='no data')?' disabled ':''; ?>></td>
        <td align='left' width='80' class='day'><a href='#' style='color:#0d8e17;font-weight:bold'>Monday</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width='30'><input type='checkbox' name='day_name2' class='daycheck' value='2' checked <? echo ($takingsArray[2]=='no data')?' disabled ':''; ?>></td>
        <td align='left' width='80' class='day'><a href='#' style='color:#f47320;font-weight:bold'>Tuesday</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width='30'><input type='checkbox' name='day_name3' class='daycheck' value='3' checked <? echo ($takingsArray[3]=='no data')?' disabled ':''; ?>></td>
        <td align='left' width='80' class='day'><a href='#' style='color:#7678ab;font-weight:bold'>Wednesday</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width='30'><input type='checkbox' name='day_name4' class='daycheck' value='4' checked <? echo ($takingsArray[4]=='no data')?' disabled ':''; ?>></td>
        <td align='left' width='80' class='day'><a href='#' style='color:#ecd77e;font-weight:bold'>Thursday</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width='30'><input type='checkbox' name='day_name5' class='daycheck' value='5' checked <? echo ($takingsArray[5]=='no data')?' disabled ':''; ?>></td>
        <td align='left' width='80' class='day'><a href='#' style='color:#84b586;font-weight:bold'>Friday</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width='30'><input type='checkbox' name='day_name6' class='daycheck' value='6' checked <? echo ($takingsArray[6]=='no data')?' disabled ':''; ?>></td>
        <td align='left' width='80' class='day'><a href='#' style='color:#bc8b7c;font-weight:bold'>Saturday</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width='30'><input type='checkbox' name='day_name7' class='daycheck' value='7' checked <? echo ($takingsArray[7]=='no data')?' disabled ':''; ?>></td>
        <td align='left' width='80' class='day'><a href='#' style='color:#015253;font-weight:bold'>Sunday</a></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody> 
    </table>        
</div>
```

```
div id="totalTakings" is the code that actually contains the graph.
```

This should be very simple, yet I cannot find the solution.

Comment: What's the width of `extrawidechartbox`?

Answer (score 1):

You could apply a specific chart size. I opened a question on this topic here : [JqPlot : Set a fix height value for the graph area not including y axe labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229577/jqplot-set-a-fix-height-value-for-the-graph-area-not-including-y-axe-labels)

The solution was to replot with exact chart size like this :

```
var w = parseInt($(".jqplot-yaxis").width(), 10) + parseInt($("#chart").width(), 10);
var h = parseInt($(".jqplot-title").height(), 10) + parseInt($(".jqplot-xaxis").height(), 10) + parseInt($("#chart").height(), 10);
$("#chart").width(w).height(h);
plot.replot();
```